# NotifyDatasetChanged not working in customListView in android

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have made a custom ListView and adapter for that, I have made a custom relative layout class for `delete` feature. Now I want to update my ListView once any of item is deleted. I have used `notifydatasetChanged()` method, But its not working. Please help me. My adapter is as below

```
public class TimelineAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Post> {

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public TimelineAdapter(Context context) {

        super(context, R.layout.list_item_post);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void setData(List<Post> data) {
        setNotifyOnChange(false); 
        clear();
        if (data != null) {
            addAll(data);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override 
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Post post = getItem(position);
        PostListItem view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view =  (PostListItem) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_post, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = (PostListItem) convertView;
        }
        view.setPost(post);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**CustomListItem**

```
if (mPost.postUser.userID == sharedConnect.mCurrentUser.userID) {
    // Log.e("Remove Post", "Success");


    //Added by jigar..
    tfragment = new TimelineFragment();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

    builder1.setMessage("Are you sure?");
    builder1.setCancelable(true);

    builder1.setPositiveButton(
            "Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();

    //open = false;
                    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

                        @Override
                        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

                            Connect sharedConnect = Connect.getInstance(getContext());
                            sharedConnect.deletePost(mPost.postID);


                            return true;
                        }


                        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Deleted",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




                        }
                    }.execute();


                }
            });

    builder1.setNegativeButton(
            "No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    //  open = false;
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
    alert11.show();


    //end
```

Comment: Post the code where you are deleting an item

Comment: you need to refresh the view after deleting an item. guess it may be in pop up.. So better use service call in onStart.

Comment: @Chol-Ok frend,Please see my update.I really need help,actually i am refreshing pull to refresh on listView and its working the same thing i want to do when i delete.

Comment: but where in the delete are you using notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: Once deleted, you need to set adpater.setData() again wiht the new list updated

Comment: @Chol-But i really have no idea where to put it.means in adapter of listitem class.

Comment: Basically, you are adding your data when calling adapter.setData(yourData). When deleting or adding item to yourData, you need to call adpater.setData(YourNewData) to be updated

Comment: But my prob is i have delete logic inside my customlistItem class,So I am really consfused,,,:(